# Evaluate $\int \frac {e^x -1}{e^x + 1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\int \dfrac {e^x -1}{e^x + 1} dx$$

My Attempt:
$$\int \dfrac {e^x -1}{e^x+1}dx=(e^x -1) \int \dfrac {1}{e^x +1} dx$$
Let $e^x =t$
$$e^x\cdot dx=dt$$
Then,
$$\int \dfrac {e^x -1}{e^x+1}dx=(e^x -1) \int \dfrac {1}{t(t+1)} dt$$

Comment: How did you pull out $e^{x}-1$ from the integral?

Comment: @clark is correct in asking this. You cannot remove any function depending on x from under the integral sign.

Comment: Oh sorry. That's my mistake. I thought it to be constant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

we have $$\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}=\frac{e^x+1-2}{e^x+1}=1-\frac{2}{e^x+1}$$ and Substitute $$e^x=t$$
the result should be $$2 \log \left(e^x+1\right)-x+C$$

Answer (score 5):

***Here is another hint :***

$$I=\int \frac {e^x -1}{e^x+1}dx=\int \frac {e^{-\frac x 2}(e^x -1)}{e^{-\frac x 2}(e^x+1)}dx$$
$$I=\int \frac {\sinh(\frac x 2)}{\cosh(\frac x 2)}dx$$
$$I=2\int \frac {du} u=2\ln(u)+K $$
$$\boxed{I=2\ln(\cosh(\frac x 2))+K}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: $$\int \dfrac {e^x -1}{e^x+1}dx=\int\left(1-\frac2{e^x+1}\right)\,dx=\int\,dx-2\int\frac{dx}{e^x+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using OP's approach:

$$\int\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}dx$$

Let $e^x=t$ and so $e^xdx=dt$. The new integral can then be written:

$$\int\frac{t-1}{t+1}\frac{1}{t}dt$$

Notice that $\frac{t+1}{t-1}=\frac{2}{t+1}+\frac{-1}{t}$, so our integral is equal to:

$$\int\frac{2}{t+1}-\frac{1}{t}dt=\int\frac{2}{t+1}dt-\int\frac{1}{t}dt=2\ln(t+1)-\ln(t)+C$$

Remembering that $t=e^x$ we finally get:

$$2\ln(e^x+1)-\ln(e^x)+C=2\ln(e^x+1)-x+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $e^x+1=t,\implies e^x\ dx=dt\implies dx=\dfrac{dt}{t-1}$

$$\implies\int\dfrac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\ dx=\int\dfrac{t-2}{t(t-1)}dt$$

Now $\dfrac{t-2}{t(t-1)}=\dfrac1{t-1}-2\cdot\dfrac{t-(t-1)}{t(t-1)}=\dfrac1{t-1}-2\left(\dfrac1{t-1}-\dfrac1t\right)=\dfrac2t-\dfrac1{t-1}$